# How to change page title of Manage Fields screen based on bundle name?

Tags: 8

Is it possible to change admin screen page title based on bundle related to the screen. For example, I would like title of `admin/structure/types/manage/datasheet/fields` page to be `Manage datasheet fields`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the static title with a dynamic title.

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/node/2067859

This describes how to define dynamic titles for new routes in yaml files. You need to change the existing route `entity.node.field_ui_fields` in a route subscriber:

```
$route->setDefault('_title_callback', '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyController::getTitle');
```

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

Comment: Thanks, I hoped, that there would be an easier solution to the problem, which is in my view a very strange UX omission.